# How can I refactor the below code to make it faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This code is developed by my colleague, and it is really slow. I don't want to create any temp table. How can I make this query faster?

```
SELECT s.MaterialNumber
    ,sum(s.Stock) Stock
    ,dbo.getSapContractNumberBySapDeliveryNumber(s.SapDeliveryNumber) SapContractNumber
    ,s.BillTo
    ,s.Quantity
INTO #tmp
FROM Stok s
GROUP BY s.MaterialNumber
    ,s.SapDeliveryNumber
    ,s.BillTo
    ,s.Quantity

SELECT DISTINCT e.SapContractNumber + '' + e.CustomerId Id
    ,e.SapContractNumber
    ,c.ContractName
    ,e.CustomerId
    ,cu.CustomerFullName
    ,e.ortalamastok
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Orders o
        WHERE o.CustomerId = e.CustomerID
            AND o.SapContractNo = e.SapContractNumber
            AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, - 1, GETDATE()), - 1)
        ) OrderCount
FROM EmniyetStok e
LEFT JOIN #tmp t ON t.SapContractNumber = e.SapContractNumber
LEFT JOIN Customers cu ON cu.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Contracts c ON c.SAPContractNumber = e.SapContractNumber
WHERE {0}
    AND e.ortalamastok > 0

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: Well don't put subqueries within your select statement for a start, that's usually a quick way to a slow query. You want to put this in your joins properly. Look at Cross Join if you don't have anything linking it back to the other data. Also, take a look at the execution plan of this query to see what's costing the most.

Comment: Also, is that a scalar valued function I see? That's going to kill your parallelism.

Comment: What is the actual WHERE clause in the second query?

Comment: BTW there is nothing wrong with temp tables if used correctly.

Comment: It would really help if you can post a schema - including any indexes that already exist, and maybe some sample data (consider SQLFiddle).

Comment: 1. Sometimes `GROUP BY` works better than `DISTINCT`. 
2. Create an index on temp table if its huge
3. Why have columns which you do not need in your temp table if its not used. remove them

Comment: To make your qry faster we need complete structure - indexes and functions too. Your problem is probably combined from both, third problem can be inner COUNT(*) because your argument is non-SARG. next problem can be in your where clause. Temp table is used at right place and you shouldn't remove it.

Comment: The function call `getSapContractNumberBySapDeliveryNumber` might also be an issue depending on what it does.

Comment: To expand on @Tanner's comment temp tables can make a process significantly *faster* when used properly.

Comment: Please post the execution plan (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ is handy for this) and, as @NevilleK stated, the details of your indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
     s.MaterialNumber
    ,sum(s.Stock) Stock
    ,dbo.getSapContractNumberBySapDeliveryNumber(s.SapDeliveryNumber) SapContractNumber
    ,s.BillTo
    ,s.Quantity
INTO #tmp
FROM Stok s
GROUP BY s.MaterialNumber
    ,s.SapDeliveryNumber
    ,s.BillTo
    ,s.Quantity

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_SapContractNumber_tmp on #tmp (SapContractNumber)

SELECT 
    Qry.Id,
    Qry.SapContractNumber,
    Qry.ContractName,
    Qry.CustomerId,
    Qry.CustomerFullName,
    Qry.ortalamastok,
    COUNT(Qry.OrderID) TotalCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            e.SapContractNumber + '' + e.CustomerId AS Id   
            ,e.SapContractNumber
            ,c.ContractName
            ,e.CustomerId
            ,cu.CustomerFullName
            ,e.ortalamastok
            ,o.OrderID -- change appropriate column name here
        FROM EmniyetStok e
        INNER JOIN Orders o
        ON o.CustomerId = e.CustomerID
        AND o.SapContractNo = e.SapContractNumber
        AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
        AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, - 1, GETDATE()), - 1)
        LEFT JOIN #tmp t ON t.SapContractNumber = e.SapContractNumber
        LEFT JOIN Customers cu ON cu.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
        LEFT JOIN Contracts c ON c.SAPContractNumber = e.SapContractNumber
        WHERE {0} AND e.ortalamastok > 0
) Qry
GROUP BY 
    Qry.Id,
    Qry.SapContractNumber,
    Qry.ContractName,
    Qry.CustomerId,
    Qry.CustomerFullName,
    Qry.ortalamastok    
DROP TABLE #tmp
```